# .NET Maui: Vector/SVG splashscreen not correctly resized

Tags: c#, .net, svg, maui, .net-maui

Testing to add a custom splash screen for a Maui app, I read some [Microsoft docs that says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/single-project#splash-screen)

> At build time, the splash screen image is resized to the correct size
> for the target platform and device. The resized splash screen is then
> added to your app package.

However, that is not what I am seeing; instead the image is capped by the screen and not adapted. Repro:

1. Install VS Studio 2022 17.1.0 Preview 3.0 and latest MAUI
2. Create a new .NET Maui App (Preview) project
3. Add an SVG file, I used this one: https://publicdomainvectors.org/download.php?file=liftarn_Black_horse.svg and place it in `Resources/Images`
4. Rename the file to "horse.svg" inside VS (otherwise you will get an build error)
5. In Properties, set the Build Action to MauiSplashScreen; this will create a new entry in the csproj file
6. I got double <MauiSplashScreen ...> tags in csproj file, so I manually removed the previous one (note: there is a bug, because the Properties panel for the svg no longer says `MauiSplashScreen`
7. Run the app on emulator, I used Pixel 2 Android Pie 9

When the splash appears, it is not adapted to the screen size, so it is capped. Looks like this (I added Red background):

[image]

but the entire SVG images looks like:

[image]

So, I wonder what the quote above means? It seems to me that I have to manually shrink the SVG/image somehow, to fit to screen?

### Update

I replace height and width in svg with a viewport instead, but the results are the same:

[image]

```
<svg 
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:cc="http://web.resource.org/cc/" 
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
    xmlns:sodipodi="http://inkscape.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" 
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    id="svg1322" sodipodi:version="0.32"
    viewBox="0 0 680 640" 
    ....

---
```

Comment: instead of a viewBox attribute the svg element has a dardcoded width and height.

Comment: Care to elaborate? How can the svg be modified to fix this?

Comment: the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: Use my SVG image control that's based on Skia instead of the Regular Image control that converts your image to a PNG and you won't face these issues. https://github.com/FreakyAli/MAUI.FreakyControls :)

Answer (score 4):

Setting the `BaseSize` fixed the issue for me - the bigger you set it the smaller the image will be.

```
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splashscreen.svg" BaseSize="128,128" />
```

(be sure to uninstall the app and do a build>clean solution)

Comment: This worked for me after changing my image to an SVG and making the image square. I used Adobe's online image converter to convert my image.  https://www.adobe.com/express/feature/image/convert/jpg-to-svg

Comment: @SirDavidJ.GarretsonM.S. nice, might I also recommend https://www.photopea.com/ use the Image>Canvas Size menu option

Comment: Could not get this to work.  BaseSize seemed to be ignored no matter what I tried.  Only thing that seemed to affect size was using a smaller image.  A 256 image seemed to size correctly.  Anything larger made it so huge it exceeded the screen like in your original submission.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simplified version of your code. I've removed the transformed groups since some tags were not closed.

As you can see I've removed the hard coded width and heighr and added a viewBox. Now rhe svg will take all the width available i.e. the width of the parent.

```html
<svg viewBox="-1400 80 680 640" >
    <path id="path1364" d="m-1183.8 149.2c-2.3 1.17-6.1 0.87-8.7 0.3-1.2-2.04-4.4-3.47-5.2-5.8-2.1-1.45-4.4-0.87-5.9-1.18 0-2.29 4.1-0.57 3.8-2.59 3.8-0.59 7.3-1.74 11.1-2.91l-0.6-0.32h2.6c-0.3 0-0.3 0-0.6 0.32 2.1 0.87 3.2 1.73 4.4 2.91 1.2 3.2 0.8 6.38-0.9 9.27m-61.9 26.14c-1.2 0.6-2.1 1.16-2.3 1.46h-5.9c1.5-1.16 2.7-2.34 3.5-4.36 0.6-1.74-1.4-3.47-2-5.81-1.5-0.27-2.9-1.16-4.9-0.27-0.4-1.74 2.9-0.29 2.6-2.34 2-0.29 4.6-0.29 6.9 0h-0.2c-0.6 1.73 3.1 1.16 2.6 2.61 1.2 1.16 1.7 2.91 1.4 4.93 0.3 1.76-0.9 2.33-1.7 3.78zm518.94 101.08c2.04-4.39-2.03-7.86-3.48-11.05-4.95-5.52-10.76-8.99-15.71-13.64-4.08 0.28-5.23-3.2-8.12-3.79 0 0.3 0.28 0.89-0.3 1.16 3.19 2.04 6.69 4.95 9.89 7.56 1.43 3.48 4.66 3.79 5.22 6.67 0.86 2.04 2.02 5.23 0.3 7.28-0.86-0.59-2.91-0.31-2.91-1.74-4.36-0.31-6.99-1.49-11.07 0-2.3 1.74-3.47 5.51-2.9 8.41-0.27 3.76 4.38 4.63 2.9 8.72 0 1.15-1.74 1.72-1.13 2.33-2.04 1.72-5.84 0.86-8.72 0.57-0.61-2.04-3.79-1.18-5.84-1.75-0.59-0.57 0.88-0.29 0-0.86-6.67-1.48-13.38-4.38-20.33-6.4l0.57-0.57c-4.65 0-9.02-2.04-13.38-3.22-7.83-1.14-15.4-0.86-23.55-0.28-4.06 0.89-8.73 2.32-11.92 5.22-7.57 7.29-11.9 16.27-16.86 24.42-2.02 0.29-1.16 3.76-3.5 2.9 1.16-4.65 5.82-9.03 5.82-14.23 0.59-3.19-1.14-7.55-2.62-9.59-4.33-3.19-7.24-8.72-11.33-12.2-3.78-1.73-7.27-4.34-10.74-6.38 0 0 0.29-0.3 0.56-0.3-0.88-0.56-2.04-0.86-2.9-0.29-0.27 2.01 2.9 0.59 2.63 2.63 0.87 0 1.44 0.56 2.3 0.56 4.08 4.64 7.86 7.86 11.63 12.48-1.16 0.87 1.18 2.04 0.61 2.64 1.14 4.91-0.61 9.27-4.09 12.48-3.2 3.17-7.27 5.51-10.45 8.98-11.63 13.95-4.95 31.95-0.29 47.08 4.34 12.77 11.63 26.39 11.03 39.17-1.74 7.84 0.28 16.86-5.81 23.51-2.9 0.31-2.9 3.21-5.22 3.21l0.56 0.6c-1.74 0.87-5.51 0-5.22 2.01l-14.83 0.31c-4.09-2.03-6.67-2.64-10.77-4.36 0.3-0.3 0.3-0.3 0.59-0.3-7.56-4.66-13.38-10.46-19.19-15.09l0.3-0.32c-3.77-2.9-7-6.38-10.77-8.71l0.3-0.27-2.92-1.15 0.3-0.3c-5.54-2.05-9.88-7.56-16.28-9.01l-7.56-1.16h0.29c-8.16-0.58-16.88-4.05-24.72-5.22 0-0.11 0.16-0.11 0.33-0.11-2.02-1.27-4.75-0.8-6.71-1.64 0.3 0 0.3-0.29 0.57-0.29-1.75-1.18-4.35-0.57-6.38-1.45 0.3-0.3 0.57-0.3 0.85-0.3-1.74-0.56-3.47-1.15-5.47-1.44 0 0 0.1-0.05 0.2-0.08-4.3-0.69-5.3-3.39-10.1-3.39l0.3-0.32c-6.1-2.59-12.3-4.34-17.8-6.67l0.3-0.57c-1.1-0.58-2.9 0-4.1-1.47l0.3-0.27c-2.9-0.3-4.9-2.91-7.2-2.91l0.5-0.59c-5.2-1.73-10.4-5.5-14.2-8.11l0.3-0.31-2.3-1.45 0.3-0.27c-0.9-1.18-3.5-0.29-2.9-2.04h0.3c-2.9-1.47-4.7-3.19-7.3-4.37 0.3-0.28 0-0.88 0.3-1.15-4.1-3.78-9.3-6.1-12.5-10.47-1.2-4.63 0.5-10.73 3.7-13.91 2.6-2.04 5-4.95 7.6-6.1l-0.3-0.32c4.7-0.57 6.7-2.59 11.4-3.18v-0.29l2.3-0.86c0.8-2.04-2.3-0.6-1.8-2.64-3.7-2.01-7-2.87-11-4.33v-0.31l-3.8-1.73c0.3-0.86-1.4-1.46-1.2-2.34 1.2-0.87 2.9-0.56 4.1-0.27 3.8 2.04 8.2 3.47 12.2 3.76 5.6-1.44 10.2-0.29 15.1-2.01 2.9 1.72 8.2 1.72 11.4 0.86 1.7-0.57-0.9-1.46-0.9-2.34-2.3-1.13-4.4-3.17-6.7-4.65l0.3-0.27c-3.8-2.63-8.4-1.75-12.2-2.63 0 0 0-0.27 0.3-0.27-1.5-1.17-3.8-0.6-5.5-1.46-0.3-1.18-3.8-2.9-5.3-3.47 0.9-1.18-2.3-0.61-1.4-2.63 0.9-0.88 2.6-0.57 3.8-0.27 2.3 1.43 6.4 1.72 9.6 2.61 2.6-1.75 7.2-0.32 9-2.61 8.1-0.61 17.1 0.57 24.7-0.89 1.1-2.31-2.6-3.19-3.8-4.05-1.4-0.31-3.5 0-4.3-1.17l0.2-0.32c-2.6-0.86-4.9-2.01-7.2-3.17 0.1-0.28 0.2-0.31 0.4-0.31-6.2-0.14-11.9-2.87-17.9-2.59-1.7-1.17-4.3-3.21-6.4-5.22 0.3-0.89-0.6-1.18 0.6-1.48 2.9-0.27 6.4 0.3 9-0.56l0.6-1.19c4.1-0.56 8.7 0 12.2-1.42-1.4-0.87-2.9-2.34-4.6-2.61 0.2-0.3 0.2-0.3 0.2-0.59-4.3 0.29-6.9-2.34-11-2.34-0.3-2.02-4.1-0.86-4.4-3.76 1.8-2.03 6.7-0.89 9.9-0.89 0 0.31-1.4 0-0.3 0.31 5.6 1.16 10.2 0.87 15.1-1.74 0.9-1.16 3.8-0.59 3.8-2.34 8.2-1.72 15.4 4.38 23.02 0.87-0.3 0-0.62 0-0.62-0.27l2.63-1.17c0.6-1.15 0-1.15 0-2.6-6.43 0-13.03-6.97-18.63-5.54-4.9-2.61-11.9-0.56-17.4-2.04 0-1.73-4.7-0.87-6.4-2.02l0.6-0.57c-3.2-0.32-5.6-2.33-7.6-4.08 5.5-0.87 11.9 0.59 18-0.3 5.3-1.74 10.2-2.61 14.9-4.65 7.2-0.27 13.62 0.33 21.19-0.57-0.59-1.72 2.05-0.85 2.91-1.72-0.86-0.88 1.75-0.88 0.86-2.33-2.91-0.3-6.4-2.05-9.01-2.61l0.3-0.29c-3.21-1.19-5.85-3.48-8.75-3.21l0.3-0.27c-7.5 0.27-15.4 1.16-22.7 0.57-4.6-1.74-9.3-4.36-13.3-7.26 1.7-1.75 2.6-2.63 4.3-3.5 0.6-2.9-3.8-1.72-4.1-4.05 5.9-1.46 11.1-2.32 16.6-4.36 0-1.45 3.5-1.73 2.9-2.61 5.3-1.75 11.7 0.27 16.3-1.75 4.4-0.27 6.42-1.45 9.62-4.06 0.28-4.35-5.82-2.02-8.72-3.2-6.1-3.47-13.7-5.24-20.7-4.62-5.2 2.29-11.9 1.43-18 1.15-2.3-2.33-5.8-1.15-8.1-3.49 0.6-1.46 2.9-2.04 3.2-2.91 5.2-2.6 10.7-3.47 15.4-5.51-0.3-0.29-2.1-1.47-1.2-1.16-3.5-1.74-6.7-1.74-9.9-3.22-5.5-0.86-11.9-0.28-17.4-1.13l0.3-0.3-4.1-1.15c0.3-1.18 2.4 0 2.9-1.18 0 0-0.5 0.29-0.5 0 3.4-0.87 7.5-0.87 11.3-1.17 7.2-2 13.1-7.55 19.7-7.84 4.1 2.04 7.9-0.57 11.9-0.57 0.7-1.45 3.3-2.6 3-4.64h-7.6c-0.9-2.35-4.9-0.87-7-2.03 0-0.32 0.3-0.32 0.6-0.32-1.7-1.72-4.9 0-5.5-2.29l-8.1-0.88s0.2-0.3 0.5-0.3c-14.2-3.2-28.5-0.56-42.4-1.15 0-1.45 2-1.75 2.3-2.61 4.7-2.64 9.6-3.2 14.5-4.95l-0.2-0.29 4-1.16-0.8-0.57 2.9-1.18c0.6-0.86 1.7-2.9 2-4.06-0.3-0.27-0.9 0-1.1-0.27-0.9 0.56-0.9 0.86-0.9 1.43-3.8-0.87-7.3-1.73-11.1-1.73-0.6-2.04-4.3-0.59-5.2-2.61-7.9-1.47-16.9 0.27-24.2-0.3 4.4-3.78 11.1-4.08 14.3-8.4-7.6 0.85-16-0.3-24.4-1.19 0.3-0.29 0.6-0.29 0.8-0.29-2 0-4.3-1.159-6.3 0.58-0.6 8.42-3.6 15.41-4.4 24.12 1.2 0 1.7 0.57 2.6 0.87-0.6 0.29 0 0.29-0.6 0.56 2.9-0.27 2.6 2.64 5 2.91 3.5 3.2 7.2 6.66 10.7 9.89 3.5 4.92 7.9 9.87 11.4 15.09 4.9 7.25 8.4 14.52 11.9 22.66 9.6 22.64 6.7 51.09 2.6 76.66-2.9 17.69-8.4 34.56-13.1 51.98-0.9 0.29-1.4 1.16-2.3 0.57 0.6-2.61-2.9-2.89-2.3-5.22-4.7-4.06 0.3-10.44 0.8-15.38 7-25.84 16.3-55.48 12.3-81.32-0.6-2.33 0.3-4.38-0.4-5.81-2.9-12.47-5.2-22.95-11.6-33.69-3.4-8.7-11-14.81-15.4-22.07-3.8-2.31-5.8-5.51-9-8.42-3.5-0.29-4.7-4.08-7.8-4.65 0.2 0 0.2-0.29 0.5-0.29-2.9-1.73-6.4-3.47-9.3-5.51 0.3-1.16 2.1-0.6 2.9-0.6 4.7-0.56 3.8-5.78 6.1-8.71 0.9-10.73 4.4-22.936 4.1-32.8-3.8 7.552-5.8 18.31-13.6 23.23-2.1 3.49-5.6 3.2-7.3 5.53l0.3 0.27c-2.3 0.6-2.9 2.34-5.6 3.2-2.6 2.61-1.7 7.85-5.8 7.54-2.3-2.02 0.6-6.97 1.2-9.58 1.7-4.06 6.7-3.76 9.9-6.38v-0.29l3.8-1.45c0.6-0.59 0.9-1.16 1.1-2.01l-8.1-1.19s0.3-0.29 0.6-0.29c-4.1-0.57-9-0.86-13.4-0.27 0.3 0.85-0.9 0.85-1.2 0.85-5.2 2.62-5.5 9.87-6.4 13.64-4 0.89-8.1 3.2-12.5 4.95l0.3 0.29c-3.2 0.3-4.3 2.61-7.5 2.91l0.3 0.29-4.4 1.44c0.3 0 0.6 0 0.6 0.31-6.1 2.9-11.6 5.49-17.2 8.13l0.3 0.26-4.3 1.48 0.2 0.3-3.1 1.44 0.2 0.3c-3.4 1.43-7.2 2.61-9.6 4.93l0.4 0.27-3.5 1.18 0.2 0.3c-3.7 2.03-9 4.93-11.9 6.96-5.2 2.89-10.4 3.49-15.7 4.94l0.3 0.27c-3.2-0.56-3.8 2.91-6.7 3.2-1.1 1.45-3.2 3.47-3.8 5.52-6.4 7.28 0.3 15.7-2.9 22.95-0.3 2.91 4.4 1.14 5.3 2.61 7 1.16 13.6 0 20.6 1.16 0 0-0.3 0.27-0.6 0.27l6.7 0.32c2.3 0.57 1.2 2.02 1.5 3.47-6.4 2.63-11.7 5.82-17.8 8.15 0.3 0 0.6 0 0.9 0.29-2.3 0.86-4.3 1.43-6.4 2.29-1.1 2.04 2.9 1.48 2.1 3.22 2.6 0.87 1.7 1.72 4.3 2.59-0.3 0-0.3 0.32-0.6 0.32 0.6 1.16 2.1 0.56 3.2 1.45-0.3 0.28-0.6 0.28-0.8 0.28 0.8 0.85 2.9 0.28 3.1 2.03 4.7 2.05 9.9 1.16 14.9-0.3-0.3-1.45 1.4-0.88 2.3-1.45l-0.3-0.28c2.1-1.17 2.9-2.92 5.6-3.48l-0.4-0.29c3.3-2.05 6.7-4.36 10.2-6.38 6.1-2.62 13.1-2.9 19.2-4.38 3.2 2.34 6.4 5.81 9.6 7.86 4.4-0.3 5.2 2.33 9.6 1.72 5.5-0.87 11.6-2.29 16.6-5.2l-0.3-0.29c3.2-0.88 4.3-4.09 7.2-4.66l-0.3-0.29c3.5-2.32 4.4-7.26 8.5-7.55 1.5 2.04-0.9 4.35-2 5.8-1.5 2.34-4.1 4.65-6.2 7.56-3.4 3.2-6.1 4.06-9 6.37-3.4 0-4.9 3.21-8.4 3.21 0.3 0 0.9 0 0.9 0.28-2.6 0.9-6.2 0.3-8.4 1.75-2.7 0.3-4.4 0.86-5.6 2.9-5.2 5.81-12.2 10.76-16.5 17.14-13.7 14.81-22.7 32.83-33.8 49.96-1.7 2.3-4.3 4.33-6.9 6.66-2.7 3.79-6.2 6.71-8.8 10.76-3.8 3.48-4.9 9.01-7.2 13.93-3.3-2.04-6.2-5.23-9.6-6.97 0 0 0.3-0.29 0.5-0.29-2-1.16-3.7-2.33-5.2-3.19h0.3l-2.6-1.73 0.3-0.32c-3.3-0.28-1.5-2.02-4.7-2.91-6.4-6.66-12.5-14.51-18-22.05-0.6-4.08-2.9-7.55-4.1-11.31-1.1-0.31-2.3-2.05-2.3-3.21-3-0.55-2.4-2.63-5.4-2.86-7.2 3.68-16.4 0-22.2 7.22-1.5 4.65-4.7 8.12-6.7 13.37-4.6 6.37-12.5 12.18-16.3 18.84-4.1 2.63-5 5.54-8.7 8.15l0.3 0.29c-3.5 2.91-6.7 5.82-10.2 8.71-6.7 3.19-7 12.21-8.7 17.71 0.6 4.37 1.4 6.12 2.3 10.74 2.3 8.15-3.2 14.81-7.3 20.33-3.7 2.34-8.1 4.37-12.2 4.37 0.6 0 0.3 0.57 0.3 0.86 3.5 0 6.7 0 9.6 1.17 0.9 1.15 1.5 3.48 1.8 4.94-1.5 4.36-1.5 11.61-2.7 16.53l1.5 0.89c-0.3 0.28-0.6 0.57-0.6 0.87 5.8 1.15 12.2 0.27 17.5-0.3 0.5-1.46 4-0.86 5.2-1.46 2.6-1.45 6.1-2.3 9.3-3.47-0.3-1.73 3.8-1.45 3.5-2.9 4.9-3.79 4-11.93 5.5-17.13l-18.3-0.61c0.9-1.42-1.2-2.58 0-4.05 4-1.43 9-2.61 13.6-4.04 0.6-3.52 0.9-7.56 3.8-9.6 1.8-3.79 6.2-5.22 9.4-7.82 3.1-1.19-0.9-4.38 0-6.7-1.5-1.44-1.8-3.5-2.7-5.22-2.6-2.33-4-4.65-7.3-5.8-0.2-2.04 2.1-3.5 3-5.52 8.4-8.14 17.1-14.81 24.4-23.22 0.5-0.62 1.4-0.89 2.3-0.62 3.2-0.86 2.3 1.77 4.7 2.63 2.6 4.65 7.2 7.86 9.3 11.62 3.2 5.8 7.5 10.46 8.7 16.26 4.1 6.97 3.5 13.93 6.1 21.2 0.6 1.44 1.7 2.33 2 3.79 3.2 2.31 9 4.92 13.4 6.36 4.4-0.56 4.9 3.2 9 2.34 0.3-6.39-2.3-13.95-0.3-21.5 1.2-2.32 2.1-5.51 3.5-8.41 1.2-0.87 1.7 0 2.6 0.56-3.2 9.59-0.5 18.61 1.2 27.6-0.6 3.48 1.7 5.52 2 8.72-4.6 3.47-9.3 1.15-14.2 1.15 0.6-0.58 1.1-0.3 1.7-0.3-5.2-0.56-9.6-2.33-14.8-3.19 0.3 0 0.3-0.29 0.6-0.29-8.7-0.27-15.2-7.24-23.6-8.42l0.6-0.29c-3.2-0.57-6.4-1.75-9.3 0 0.3 0 0.9-0.28 0.9 0.29-5.2 1.47-6.7 9.01-8.8 13.36-6.3 8.15 1.8 15.41 2.1 23.22 0.6 3.79 2.3 7.58 2.3 10.74 1.2 14.53 1.5 29.65 3.5 43.88 1.2 3.19 4.7 5.22 5.5 8.39 2.7 0.32 4.4 2.9 7 2.9-0.3 0.32-0.3 0.32-0.6 0.32 1.2 0.88 3 0.28 3.8 1.72h-0.3c2.6 0.6 3.8 2.62 6.4 3.21l-0.3 0.29c2.1 1.75 3.8 2.6 5.5 4.65 0.9 2.32 0.6 4.94 2.1 6.97 0.8 4.91 1.4 9.29 0.3 14.78 2 1.21 1.7-2.01 3.2-2.28l-0.3-0.3c1.2-1.47 3.2-0.59 4.6-0.59 2.6 3.49 6.1 5.81 9.3 8.99 0.9 1.47 2.1 2.91 2.9 4.64 1.2 0.3 3.5 0.89 4.4-0.54 1.2-1.46 2.3-2.9 3.5-4.67 4.9-11.91 12.5-27 4.4-38.89-2.7-1.77-3.6-4.68-5.8-5.8-3.2 7.5-6.7 11.88-9.7 19.44-1.4 0-3.2-0.32-4.3-0.89 0.9-6.94 4.3-13.63 7.3-19.76-2.4 0-4.7 0-6.4-1.17-0.6-1.12-1.8-2.3-2.7-3.44-1.7-7 0-12.49 1.8-20.64-0.6-0.56-2.3 0.32-2.1-1.16l-10.4-1.14c0.8-0.29 1.7-0.29 2.6-0.29h-6.7c0.3 0 0.9 0 1.2 0.29-3.2-0.29-6.1 1.74-8.4 0.26-1.8-11.04-1.8-22.08-2.1-32.8 6.7-2.31 13.4 2.34 20.4 3.78-0.4 0.28-0.6 0.57-0.9 0.57l4.1 1.18-0.7 0.56c3 0.3 3.9 2.62 6.8 2.91l-0.9 0.87c1.4 0.29 2.9 0.29 4.1 0.85l-0.9 0.89c1.2 0.32 2.6 0.32 3.5 1.16l-0.6 0.58c2.6 0 3.5 2.62 5.8 2.62l-0.6 0.56 3.2 1.49-0.5 0.55c3.4-0.55 2.9 2.91 6.1 2.61l-0.6 0.89c1.1 0.27 2.3 0.27 3.5 1.16-0.3 0-0.3 0.3-0.6 0.3 4.6 2.33 9.6 4.36 13.9 7.26 4.7 1.15 9.6 2.89 14.6 4.92 3.5 0.29 8.1 1.47 11.3 0 0.9-2.03 2.9-3.46 3.8-5.22 6.1-9.01 6.4-19.45 7-29.34 0.5 0.59 1.7-0.87 2.3 0.29 2.6 11.91-0.6 24.13-1.2 36.03 3.2 0.27 3.2 3.19 6.4 3.19l-0.6 0.57c0.9 0.58 3 0.58 3 1.76l3.5 1.42-0.4 0.3 2.9 1.18-0.8 0.88c1.2 0.28 2.6 0.28 3.8 0.84-0.9 0.31-0.3 0.6-0.3 0.87 1.1 0 1.7 0.88 2.9 1.2l-0.6 0.28c3.2 2.63 7 2.63 9.6 5.21h-0.3c3.5 0.86 6.4 3.5 9.6 5.24h-0.3l4.1 1.43-0.6 0.58 4.1 1.19-0.6 0.59c1.4 0.27 2.9 0.27 3.8 1.43h-0.3c0.8 0.89 2.6 0.89 3.7 1.15l-0.2 1.17c3.8-1.17 4 2.89 7.8 2.6 0 0-0.3 0.29-0.6 0.29 5.8 2.62 12.8 5.25 18.3 6.41l-0.2 0.58c7.8 0.29 16.5 4.92 23.5 7.24 6.1-0.27 8.7 2.63 14.5 2.63 0 0-0.2 0.27-0.2 0.58 6.6 1.17 12.7 2.32 19.2 2.9 0 0.29-1.2 0-0.7 0.29 3.8 1.17 8.2 0.57 12 1.45l-0.3 0.32c10.2-0.32 18.6 3.18 28.8 3.18-0.3 0-0.3 0.27-0.6 0.27l3.2 1.15c1.2 9.04 1.4 17.15 2.6 25.86 1.2 3.19 2 6.96 2.9 9.87 3.2 2.64-1.7 3.22-0.3 5.81-1.4-0.56-2-2.9-3.2-3.78-2-4.07-2.9-6.98-5.2-10.42-2.1-5.53-4.1-11.07-5-16.58-0.2-4.06-6.6-1.72-9.8-2.9 0.5-0.31 1.4-0.31 2-0.31l-17.2-1.12c0-0.21 0.3-0.28 0.5-0.32-4.3-1.17-9.5-0.88-13.5-1.73 0.2-0.27 0.6 0 0.8 0-1.7-0.87-3.5-1.16-5.5-0.87 3.8 11.02 8.2 22.95 15.1 32.54 4.7 4.34 8.8 9.56 12.5 13.93 2.6-0.29 1.5 2.61 3.8 2.29 2.3 5.25 8.7 8.15 10.8 13.95 0.3 12.81 2 22.96-1.8 35.74-9.6 11.6-16.8 26.13-27 35.73-3.8 3.74-8.5 5.81-12.5 9.55-6.4 4.08-9.9 12.21-15.4 17.13-5 2.04-11.4 4.68-16.9 4.68-0.3 1.42 1.8 1.73 1.8 2.9 0.3 8.98-7.6 16.81-8.5 25.84 2.3 0.29 4.4 2.58 7.3 1.72 5.8 2.34 13.6 1.18 20.3 0.86 3.2-2.02 7 0.32 9.6-2.29 6.4-2.9 10.5-9.32 12.5-15.99-0.5-0.31-1.7-0.58-1.1-0.84-5.6 0-11.4-2.07-16.3-2.37-0.6-1.43 0-3.76 0.6-5.5 6.1-1.43 14.5 2.07 19.2-2.05l-0.3-0.27c2.6-2.01 4-5.21 7.5-5.81l-0.3-0.29c5.6-1.46 11.7-4.04 16.9-4.04v-0.32l4.4-0.57c0.5-4.09 0.5-10.17-2.4-13.08-0.5-1.75-2.9-2.62-2.3-4.64 7.6-9.58 14.6-21.21 24.1-28.44 3.5-2.31 7.6-3.21 10.52-4.94 4.93-3.19 10.15-5.82 13.64-9.31 0.58-1.74 4.11-5.21 2.32-8.11-1.13-7.3-2.6-14.81-3.47-22.39 1.15-0.29 2.34 0 2.91 0.89-0.3 0.31-0.3 0.31-0.57 0.31 4.05 1.12 6.95 5.18 11.02 6.66-0.27 0-0.27 0.27-0.57 0.27 3.2 0.59 4.66 3.79 7.86 4.67l-0.87 0.86c1.44 0.29 2.62 0.29 4.04 0.87-0.26 0.31-0.56 0.31-0.85 0.31 5.54 2.01 10.46 5.5 16.55 6.68-0.27 0-0.27 0.27-0.56 0 1.18 1.72 4.95 0.27 5.52 2.28 6.68 7.55 14.53 15.73 20.64 23.85 2.05 3.19-0.29 5.52-1.15 8.41-3.78 13.34-10.77 24.68-17.75 36.01-7.56 7.86-13.08 13.66-18.89 22.64-1.46 1.45-3.2 3.49-5.52 4.66l0.26 0.27c-6.08 3.21-12.48 6.11-18.87 7.56 1.43 1.15 2.62 3.48 2.33 5.26-2.06 7.24-4.96 13.63-9.3 18.84-1.48 1.49-1.18 2.62 0.3 3.5 3.17 0.89 5.81 1.72 9.29 2.32l-0.29 0.27c8.43 1.21 19.46 1.21 27.9 0 8.43-2.59 13.66-9.28 16-17.99-0.86-0.3-2.05-0.3-2.05-0.87l-10.15-1.15 0.27-0.32c-2.61-0.86-6.38 0-8.99-1.16 1.13-2.02 1.72-4.33 3.47-5.51 5.82 0 12.5-0.28 17.15 0.29 3.2-4.03 5.54-7.83 9.59-11.31 3.2-2.32 7.29-4.07 10.76-4.33l-0.26-0.33 11-1.16c1.76-4.64 0.62-9.59-2.59-12.49-0.58-1.44-2.34-3.45-3.49-3.77-1.16-1.45-2.01-3.17-1.75-4.95 3.2-8.7 6.97-16.53 11.07-25.55 6.1-12.75 18.87-20.32 21.21-34.84-0.3-4.03 2.04-9.31-2.62-11.32-1.47-2.01-2.9-3.2-3.77-4.33-2.9 0-1.77-2.64-4.38-2.64-2.9-3.17-5.82-7.55-8.42-10.45-4.07-6.97-8.72-11.91-12.23-18.31-1.75-1.14-3.77-2.61-4.34-3.77l-0.31-2.03c6.69-13.37 16.01-25.85 22.09-38.62 6.12-13.65 15.13-33.1 6.98-49.64 1.18-0.62 2.34-0.62 2.63-1.77h4.66c2.05 3.49 3.48 5.27 5.22 8.44 3.21 0.27 1.76 2.31 4.66 2.63l-0.88 0.55 3.79 0.59c0.59 0.88-0.88 0.56 0 1.16 1.45 0.28 2.9 0.28 4.36 1.15-0.28 0-0.28 0.29-0.57 0.29l4.33 1.48c-0.28 0-0.28 0.28-0.55 0.28l3.17 1.45c-0.26 0.29-0.26 0.29-0.57 0.29 0.57 0.59 2.91 1.16 1.73 2.02 4.09 4.67 0 12.21-2.02 17.72 3.77-4.33 5.54-10.76 9.32-14.53 0.86-3.46 1.16-6.64 1.16-10.15 0.86-0.28 1.45 0.28 2.01 1.15 0.59 2.91 3.2 3.5 4.07 5.54 4.09 1.16 8.45 0.27 12.81 0.85 0 1.78 3.48 1.18 2.91 2.91h2.04c0.57-3.19-0.32-6.39-0.88-9.3-2.91-4.33-8.16-7.24-9.03-12.75-2.04-1.77-3.76-3.2-5.21-5.21 1.15-0.89 3.17-0.33 4.65 0.54l-0.59 0.58c1.15 0.3 2.63 0.3 3.76 1.19l-0.56 0.27c2.62 1.45 6.39 1.17 9.29 0.31 3.79-0.31 4.38 2.91 8.15 2.32 1.17-0.62 3.49-0.29 3.21-1.77l9.58-0.86c0.89-2.31-1.44-3.8-2.01-5.49h0.27c-2.89-1.2-5.79-2.63-8.14-3.22-1.45-1.46-2.91-2.58-4.09-4.36-1.16 0-2.59-0.29-3.76-0.6-0.31-0.84-0.87-2.01 0.29-3.16 3.47-0.87 7.56-0.6 10.77 0.55 0 1.2 2.61 0.87 3.47 2.61 5.52 1.78 8.16-3.44 11.62-4.03-0.28 0-0.55 0-0.86-0.29 1.17-1.18 3.21-0.32 4.64-1.18-1.16-1.16-0.86-3.75-3.18-3.46-0.88-1.75-4.06-0.88-5.81-1.75l0.59-0.6-3.8-1.16c-0.58-1.74-2.91-3.17-3.2-4.06-2.05-0.89-2.61-2.63-4.95-2.9 0-0.59 0.32-0.59-0.26-1.16 2.3-1.15 5.21-0.26 7.55-0.59 0.57-2.04 3.48-1.16 3.48-2.3 3.5-1.76 6.99-2.91 10.19-2.05 0.87 1.45 4.34 0.88 6.39 0.29l-0.3-0.29 2.9-0.86c-0.56-1.76 1.46-1.48 0.87-2.91-0.56 0-1.74 0-2.01-1.16l0.27-0.32c-4.07-2.01-7.85-3.75-10.75-6.94-6.7-1.77-13.67 1.14-19.76-0.59-1.17-1.75-4.66-1.45-6.98-2.04 0-0.29 0.31-0.29 0.58-0.29-3.8-0.58-7.57 0.88-10.48 2.03h0.3c-2.03 0-3.77 1.76-5.52 0.6 2.01-2.63 3.76-4.95 6.69-5.8 1.74-1.75 5.21-3.5 8.11-4.07l-0.27-0.31c6.4-1.73 14.54 0.31 21.24-1.44l-0.29-0.29 4.07-1.18-0.31-0.28c2.62-0.86 3.48-2.3 5.25-3.76 4.05-0.29 7.54 1.13 11.34 0.86 2.32-1.75 5.81-2.02 6.97-4.65 2.02-0.88 4.66-0.57 6.68-0.26 3.2 0.86 3.2-2.35 6.11-2.35 0-1.18 1.45-1.45 2.02-2.6-4.07-1.75-7.83-4.95-12.19-7.28-2.05-2.3-6.39-0.58-9.91-1.44 0-2.33-2.29-0.29-2.9-2.03 3.49 0.56 6.42-2.02 9.6-2.02 0-0.32 0.3-0.59 0-0.89 3.21-2.01 6.4-3.76 9.6-3.47 2.33 0.27 7.27 4.04 11.05 2.61-0.29-1.75 2.04-0.86 2.91-1.75-0.57-0.86 1.16-1.75 0.85-2.62-1.42-0.28-3.2-0.28-4.63-0.87-0.59-0.57-2.91-2.32-4.08-3.18 0-0.3-0.3-0.88 0-1.15-3.48 0.56-2.61-2.64-5.82-2.64 0 0 0.07-0.06 0.21-0.12-3.36-1.01-6.45-1.04-10.09-1.04-3.47-2.9-7.86-6.09-12.51-7.24 0.88-3.21 4.65-0.88 7.29-1.19-0.3 0.31-0.3 0.31-0.6 0.31 2.35 1.45 5.82 0.88 8.43 0.57 4.36-1.75 7.57-4.92 12.22-4.35 1.17 2.31 5.23 0.29 6.11 2.6 4.35 0.87 8.99 0 11.9-2.04 0.3-1.13 2.34-2.29 2.05-3.47-4.06-0.29-6.97-1.72-10.17-3.19-1.73-2.32-4.66-3.18-6.11-5.82-1.16-0.85-3.48 0.3-3.78-1.72l-17.44-0.58c-3.21-1.75-5.52-3.77-9.02-3.77 0-0.31 0.59-0.31 0.86-0.31-1.42-1.15-4.33-0.58-6.08-1.46l0.87-0.57c-2.92-0.86-6.41-0.29-9.32-1.16 1.48-2.9 5.81-2.9 7.85-4.65 4.07-0.29 8.46-0.29 12.23 0 2.61 2.62 7.83 0.57 10.47 2.62 6.68 0.86 12.48 0.58 19.47 0.29 1.45-1.16 4.06-2.02 5.8-3.2 0.9-1.43 1.19-2.91 2.92-3.77 1.74-3.77 0.29-10.17-2.35-13.36-0.57-3.2-5.19-4.92-4.33-8.72 5.22-0.86 9.58 3.8 14.53 1.46 0-0.28-0.59-0.28-0.59-0.57l2.91-0.89c-1.16-1.15 0.6-1.44 0.87-2.01z"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it didnt work when I replace the height and width with the viewbox,s ame issue. Updated the question.