# ..net maui splash screen change not displaying correctly

Tags: maui

I'm experimenting with .net maui.  i'm using vs 17.3 preview 4.  I'd like to change the spash screen.  i would think that i would change the content of the spash.svg file.  I've changed the content of the file.  I've left the property of the file as mauispashscreen.  I've created a simple png file and have converted it with an online svg converter.  the file is viewable with msft edge browser.  All i get is a purple screen without the text changes.  I'm just trying to do something simple.  what should i look for in the setup of the file or the project?  any suggestions are appreciated.

Wally

Comment: I created image with black colored text and white background, with size 120px x 120px .png file then converted into .svg (online)

Answer (score 2):

At first, please double click your project and check if there is the code in your projectname.csproj file or not. It seems when you delete the splash.svg file and add a new one in the resources, the code will be auto deleted.

```
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" />
```

And then, I have tried to convert a png to svg, but the picture can't show perfectly as the splash. So I download a svg from the svg picture website and it can work well.

It seems maui can't make all the svg show as the splash screen perfectly. You can also download one instead of converting the png.

Comment: this time i created a small image, and it was there.  next question, how do i get the svg to scale to take up the screen?

Comment: I can't find a way to make all the image auto filled the splash screen. I try the solutions in [the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70799185/net-maui-vector-svg-splashscreen-not-correctly-resized) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72249499/maui-blazor-gradient-splash-screen). But you can have a try. The point of it should be the size of the svg itself. @WallaceB.McClure