# .net MAUI Splash screen android error - failed linking file resources

Tags: android, maui, .net-maui

I'm trying to add a splash screen as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?tabs=android):

```
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\appsplash.svg" Color="#fff" />
```

The resource is in the appropriate directory with the 'MauiSplashScreen' Build Action

[image]
[image]

Works fine debugging on windows but trying to build/debug on android gives the following errors:

```
Error   APT2061 failed linking file resources.
Error   APT2260 resource drawable/appsplash (aka appname:drawable/appsplash) not found.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the format of the SVG; not sure what was wrong with the format exactly but adding a different SVG solved the issue

Comment: Just like [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73072433/net-maui-splash-screen-change-not-displaying-correctly/73075735#73075735), it seems maui can now show all the svg correctly.

Comment: Yes, will do. SO makes me wait 24hrs to do that, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Had this exact same issue. but my SVG is valid.

Resolved by Build -> 'Clean Solution', followed by 'ReBuild'.

Answer (score 0):

In the official docuement, `Include="Resources\appsplash.svg"` is a full path, so you can change your code such as:

```
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Raw\appsplash.svg" Color="#fff" />
```

In addition, the build action of the splash svg is None, you can open the Splash Folder to check it.

So I suggest you put it in the Splash Folder and set its build action as none. Just like the default project does.

Comment: In my example the svg is not under the Raw directory. I did as you suggested and created a Splash Folder as in the default project (I think I made this project before that was the default as I was using a preview version). Yet still the problem persists. In the default project the build action is MauiSplashScreen too. Setting the build action to none removes the line from the csproj entirely.

Comment: So I just tested changing the svg to the default one and it works so it mustn't like the format of my svg! - yet I'm using one the exact same format as one that works for the app icon

Comment: So when you put it in the splash folder and set its build action as MauiSpashScreen, the error was still here? Did you try to download a svg and use it? I tried downloading one on the svg icon website and it worked.@Jimmy

Comment: Yes, the error was still there in that case. Downloading and using a different SVG solved the issue, not sure what it didn't like about my original one.